# How do I rewrite this to include a debug statement?

Tags: javascript

Previously I had this.

```
onSuccess: this.receiveRequest.bind(this, callback)
```

This returns a function with receive Requests's this bound to to this supplied to bind -- which is the same `this` that contains the `receiveRequest` method.

So I tried rewriting that..

```
onSuccess   : function () {                      
  console.log({'XXX: onSuccess': this});         
  return this.receiveRequest.call(this, callback)
}.bind(this),
```

However this doesn't work.. Why? Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"?

Comment: Have you tried passing `callback` into function()?

Comment: @SurrealDreams like `.bind(this, callback)` ? I though this too.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.bind(this)` on the `onSuccess` function, it's making the context of `this` the `window` or global object - try removing it. It should be trivial to throw debug logic in there, but given the binding and explicit declaring of context it looks like you may or may not be trying to achieve something more similar to this...

```
// ...

receiveRequest: function(callback) {
  console.log('received');
  callback();
},
onSuccess: function (cb) {                      
  console.log({'XXX: onSuccess': this});         
  return this.receiveRequest.bind(this, cb)
}

// ...

var requestReceivedFunc = myObj.onSuccess(function() {
   console.log('my callback'); 
});
requestReceivedFunc();
```